# Problem to use VueI18n outside a component

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-component, vue-i18n

I'm trying to use i18n outside a component I've found this solution https://github.com/dkfbasel/vuex-i18n/issues/16 telling to use Vue.i18n.translate('str'), but when I call this occurs an error Cannot read property 'translate' of undefined.

I'm using the following configuration

**main.js**

```
import i18n from './i18n/i18n';
new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    i18n: i18n,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

**i18n.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import i18nData from './i18nData'
Vue.use(VueI18n);
export default new VueI18n({
  locale: 'en',
  messages: i18nData,
});
```

**i18nData.js**

```
export default {
    en: {
        //my messages
    }
}
```

Then I trying to use this

```
import Vue from 'vue';
Vue.i18n.translate('someMessage');
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: using like this Vue.$i18n.translate() same error. Cannot read property 'translate' of undefined

Comment: The previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61679916/18450927) from @Timm actually worked for me

Answer (score 62, accepted):

To use [`i18n` with Vue 3's composition API](https://vue-i18n-next.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/composition.html), but outside a component's `setup()`, [you can access](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/lazy.html#:%7E:text=outside%20of%20the%20component) its translation API (such as the `t` function) on its [`global` property](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/api/general.html#global).

E. g. in a file with unit-testable composition functions:

```js
// i18n/index.js

import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import en from './en.json'

  ...

export default createI18n({
  datetimeFormats: {en: {...}},
  locale: 'en',
  messages: { en }
})
```

```js
// features/utils.js

//import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
//const { t } = useI18n() // Uncaught SyntaxError: Must be called at the top of a `setup` function

import i18n from '../i18n'

const { t } = i18n.global
```

Comment: This example do **not** use composition API mode of vue-i18n. For that you need  createI18n({ legacy: false; })

Comment: @gagarine Is your comment about initialization only? can you provide better example?

Answer (score 14):

You should import `i18n` instead of Vue

```
import i18n from './i18n'

i18n.tc('someMessage')
```

Comment: This worked, but in case the language was changed I need to apply on the instance of VueI18n, right?

Comment: It is automatically applied if your component is reactive.

Comment: Thanks, I'm starting with Vue, what I need to do to make the component reactive in this case?

Comment: It depends on the case. Most of the time I change locale by using `i18n.locale = 'en'` (or `this.$i18n.locale = 'en'` in Vue component). It should work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.

Comment: When i try this I get "TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite." 
It works but how can i clear this warning?

Answer (score 8):

You can use **VueI18n** outside components by importing **i18n** then, use "**t**" from **i18n.global**.

"**t**" doesn't need "**$**" and you can change **Locale** with **i18n.global.locale**.

```js
import i18n from '../i18n';

const { t } = i18n.global;

i18n.global.locale = 'en-US'; // Change "Locale"

const data = { 
  name: t('name'), // "t" doesn't need "$"
  description: t('description'), // "t" doesn't need "$"
};
```

Comment: Alas, `Property 'global' does not exist on type 'typeof import("x/node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n")'.ts(2339)`

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it work this way:

```
import router from '../router';
```

Translate a text:

```
let translatedMessage = router.app.$t('someMessage');
```

Get the current language:

```
let language = router.app.$i18n.locale;
```